# Android Studio - Can't zoom in/out in Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, sdk

Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 28, 2019

Exact same problem as asked here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53825779/android-studio-cant-zoom-in-out-in-layout-editor

However, none of the answers to that question have resolved my issue.

The issue occurs only in a new project i.e. I can open old projects and it is fine. But in a newly created project, the zoom is stuck on 7% and will not shift.

If I change the device it will zoom in and out but on Phone it will not. I have tried using the + and - in the action bar, using ctrl + and ctrl - on the keyboard, invalidating cache and restart, changing theme back and forth, I have tried closing and then importing the project from the hard-drive, nothing I do has had any effect (other than switching device to Wear). This is a new project with nothing but an Empty Activity. I have tried a new project with a Basic Activity and it is the same.

I'm at a complete loss as to what to try next.

Update: I went ahead and started working on a project and after creating some extra activities and layouts, the zoom is working fine. However, I opened a new project with an Empty Activity and zoom does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "Select Design Surface" to another value, and then you can put the initial value again. I don't know why, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After I dragged the lower border of the layout editor window down it started working.