# Is anyone else not able to pinch to zoom in Android studio 4.1?

Tags: android, macos-catalina, android-studio, ide

After upgrading to Android Studio 4.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6 I noticed that the pinch to zoom functionality no longer worked.

As of Android Studio 4.0.1 I could pinch to zoom on my computer to zoom into the text in the editor tabs where the code I'm working on is.

Searches for this issue on Google yield results for multi-touch on Android phones.

I am not referring to pinching and zooming in the Layout Editor like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1405035/android-studio-cant-zoom-in-out-in-layout-editor).

Comment: What OS do you use? This might be important as the UI interaction is first processed by the OS.

Comment: I'm on macOS Catalina

Comment: Even I am also facing the same issue. It works perfectly on Android Studio 3.6 but not on 4.1. I am on macOS mojave

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176782037
I have raised the issue on above link